# Copy table data from one server to other server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

ServerA

```
Table1
Id  Name    State   Country
1   Abc OH  USA

Table2
Id  Counties    Places
1   abc     def
1   koi     koii
1   joi     joio
```

ServerB

```
Table1
Id  Name    State   Country

Table2
Id  Counties    Places
```

I have 2 servers ServerA and ServerB under both servers there are two tables Table1/Table2 i am trying to copy single rows from Table1 and associated rows from Table2 to ServerB's Table1 and Table2.

This is how i tried doing it:

```
connection1 = connection to ServerA
connection2 = connection to ServerB

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table1 where id = 1");
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table2 where id = 1");

Connection1.Open();
Connection2.Open();

SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

var value1 = reader1.read();
var value2 = reader2.read();
```

i use `SqlDataReader` and execute above commands and get the data and insert it into `ServerB Table1 and Table2`.
Is this correct way to do this? Can a better sql command be used?

Comment: If both are Sql-Server databases, you should link both servers and copy them in database directly per sql instead of loading all into memory first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using **SQLBULKCOPY** [(See Example here)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy) which is much faster especially if you have huge data

Comment: So should i run SqlBulk 2 times? To copy over both tables?

Comment: yes.. You could create a function for SQLBULKCOPY with parameters and call two times

Comment: Even if both tables are associated with each other like are parent child. There is no way to do single copy and insert?

Comment: Sorry to bother you but one more question- What happens to primary key in this case? Does target table generate primary key itself or that is also inserted from source table?

Comment: you can do either way.. If the target table has identity column , then you dont have to transfer  it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16371/discussion-between-noviceme-and-joe-g-joseph)

Answer (score 0):

Most databases allow you to connect to other databases.  The particular sytnax is highly database dependent.  However, once you do, you can do something like:

```
select *
into server2.<db2>.<schema2>.table2
from server1.<db>.<schema>.table1
```

or

```
create table server2.<db2>.table2 as
    select *
    from server1.<db>.table1
```

(The syntax depends on the database.  The first is sql-server-like the second is oracle-like.)

Using a linked server is definitely the best way to go, if your data has any size.  By reading it into memory, you may be tempted to read and insert one row at a time.  If you have more than a few dozen rows, you'll find this way more time consuming than necessary.

Comment: I cannot use linked servers. As i dont have any access permissions to databases. I can only use connection strings to connect to database. I am using SQL2008. Any suggestions how i can do this now?